# Custom search filter in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have listed some invoice in my listing page. I have multiple search input. I want to search related data which I will upload in related field.

I have `Invoice Number`, `Customer Name`, `From Date`, `To Date` and `status` search input box. if I enter something in `Invoice Number` field This text should be search from the `Invoice Number` column from invoice listing data.
Same as other field.

See my screenshot. There have only two search field `Invoice Number` and `Customer Name` I will add more filter.

[image]

Please say me how to filter it?

I have tried with below filter. But that one not working.

Filter Input:

```
<input name="invoice_number" placeholder="Invoice Number" class="form-control ng-model="invoice_name" type="text">
<input name="customer_name" placeholder="Customer Name" class="form-control" ng-model="customer_name" type="text">
```

Listing:

```
<tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| filter:invoice_name | filter:customer_name">       
     <td>{{ x.invoice_number}}</td>                      
     <td>{{ x.customer_name}}</td>                          
     <td >{{ x.company_name}}</td>                          
     <td style="text-align: right;">{{ x.total_invoice | currency : $}}</td>                          

     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ x.created | datetime }}</td>      
     <td style="text-align: center;">                                  
         <a href="preview-invoice/{{x.unique_id}}"   target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Preview Invoices" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></button></a>
         <a href="download-invoice/{{x.invoice_number}}.pdf" ><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Download Invoices" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button></a>
    </td>                       
</tr>
```

If I searched `2016113CC` in `Customer Name` field I am getting wrong filter. See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `filter:{InvoiceField : invoice_name}`

Comment: @Weedoze What is `InvoiceField` ?

Comment: The name of the property inside `x`

Comment: Please add the code inside `<tr></tr>`

Comment: @Weedoze updated my question. Can you please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define on what property your input will be used

```
<input name="invoice_number" placeholder="Invoice Number" class="form-control ng-model="invoice_name" type="text">
<input name="customer_name" placeholder="Customer Name" class="form-control" ng-model="customer_name" type="text">
<tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| filter:{invoice_number : invoice_name} | filter:{customer_name : customer_name}">       
     <td>{{ x.invoice_number}}</td>                      
     <td>{{ x.customer_name}}</td>                          
     <td >{{ x.company_name}}</td>                          
     <td style="text-align: right;">{{ x.total_invoice | currency : $}}</td>                          

     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ x.created | datetime }}</td>      
     <td style="text-align: center;">                                  
         <a href="preview-invoice/{{x.unique_id}}"   target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Preview Invoices" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></button></a>
         <a href="download-invoice/{{x.invoice_number}}.pdf" ><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Download Invoices" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button></a>
    </td>                       
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please say me what is `invoice_number` and `invoice_name` in ng-repeat filter? I guess `invoice_number` is `name` of the  invoice number field. Am I right?

Comment: This is solution is not robust, If I need to search for 10 column headers, you saying I need to repeat filters?

Comment: Oh I see the probs, it should be `x.invoice_number` and not `x. invoice_name`

Comment: @Chinmay235 It is from the `x` object `x.invoice_number`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like this, you'll bind the search to an overall name:

```
<input name="invoice_number" placeholder="Invoice Number" class="form-control ng-model="search.invoice_number" type="text">
<input name="customer_name" placeholder="Customer Name" class="form-control" ng-model="search.customer_name" type="text">

<tr class="gradeU ng-scope" ng-repeat="x in invoice | filter:search">
    //more code here
</tr>
```

Comment: If I search invoice number `2016113CC` in `Customer Name` filed then my result should be null. Because `2016113CC` this not customer name.

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't should you anything because that `input` will only search for invoices that match customer name. So entering `2016113CC` should show nothing. But then if you want null to show you'll need to leverage on `ng-if`

Comment: I am guess you want to show a message when you enter `2016113CC` into `Customer Name` probably a message like `Not Found`.

Comment: See my updated question. 1 record coming instead of empty row. I have already put a condition `<div ng-if="invoice.length==0">No record found<div>`

Comment: No no I am asking about search filter. look my updated question.

Comment: To check you'll need to do more than that. `| filter:search as searched ` then `<div ng-if="searched.length==0">No record found<div>`

Comment: Let it I got my answer from Weedoze

Answer (score 0):

After follow the @Weedoze answer I have created multiple filter with sorting. Please check this link -

https://github.com/AngularJScript/AngularJS-Search-Multiple-Sort-column-Filter-Example

#### [Demo](https://angularjscript.github.io/Search-Multiple-fields-and-Sorting-AngularJS/)